# Show output of System.out.println

Tags: java

How do I show the output of `System.out.println("Hello World!")`?

I can only get the output when using `System.err.println("Hello World!")`.

I'm running the java program from the command line.

Comment: you are going to have to provide some more context, about the system you are running it on and how you are issuing the command.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.2 and running the `java` command through GNU Bash 3.2.48 with Java SE 1.6.0_26

Comment: Can you show us the command you are using to start the java process?

Comment: java -cp bin com.rs2lite.RS2Lite

Comment: That's a strange one!  Can you do things like `echo hello` from the command prompt OK?

Comment: please add the code of the class, maybe it's actually a syntax error of some other part of the code and because of that it's only capable of outputing an error.

Comment: It is located here: https://github.com/Tyilo/RS2Lite however it will always fail to load the URL. If you change try inserting `System.out.println("Hello World!")` inside the main class (com.rs2lite.RS2Lite), it will not get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should see both traces (out and err).

Have you redirected the output when running the command (for example: "java MyClass > myLogFile.log")?

Are you using pipes (for example: "java MyClass | grep something")?